# How do I create a new object based on clicked element in ES6?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, event-handling

I'm developing a simple web game using ES6. There is an item list and the player can buy an item by clicking the list. The code is as follows:

**index.html**

```
<ul>
  <li id="a">item A</li>
  <li id="b">item B</li>
  <li id="c">item C</li>
</ul>
```

**items.js**

```
class ItemA() {...}
class ItemB() {...}
class ItemC() {...}
```

**index.js**

```
myItems = [];

$('#a').on('click', () => {
  let item  = new ItemA();
  myItems.push(item);
});

$('#b').on('click', () => {
  let item  = new ItemB();
  myItems.push(item);
});

$('#c').on('click', () => {
  let item = new ItemC();
  myItems.push(item);
});
```

I can do this work, of course. However, if the number of items is 100 or more, I should write 100 or more event listeners. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create one object where key is the `id` and value is the class.

```js
class ItemA {}
class ItemB {}
class ItemC {}

let items = {
  a: ItemA,
  b: ItemB,
  c: ItemC
}

let myItems = []

$("li").click(function() {
  let id = $(this).attr("id");
  myItems.push(new items[id]);
  console.log(myItems)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="a">item A</li>
  <li id="b">item B</li>
  <li id="c">item C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is it inevitable to add each key? I still have to write 100 or more keys :(

Comment: Are you sure you need 100 or more different classes?

Comment: You could also do this https://jsfiddle.net/hxn8uL94/1/, but at some point you are going to have to write all those classes otherwise i don't see the point of using them.

Comment: Actually, I need 23 different classes now. I think it can be increased in the future.

Comment: @Caesium133 You need to define the relationship between id attributes and classes explicitly, one way or another. A map like `items` is a suitable way to do that If you hope for a cleaner solution, consider re-asking the question with full information regarding your problem and not the expected solution; this may be XY problem. It's unnecessary that there should be a bunch of classes that behave similarly.